# How to make subgroups by prefixes from ICD data?

Tags: r, string, sum, icd

I have a large ICD-10 data and I would like to create subgroups and get a sum out of it.

For example, I have 'JAL01, JAL20 and JAL21' and I would need a sum of all the codes starting with 'JAL'. How do I do that?

Comment: Would this be of any help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group

Comment: Does it always start with 3 letters?

Comment: @zx8754 Yes, if I do it in the way that I was planning to do it. The more letters I use, the more spesific it is.

Comment: @heilala This isn't working with me. I guess I would first need to somehow cut these 'JAL01' 's into subgroups...

Comment: @Elina Could you share a short example of the dataframe you are working with and maybe some code you used trying to solve the problem? It might be easier to recommend solutions.

Comment: @Elina then the answer below by zx8754 should do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substring first 3 letters, then group by and sum:

```
# example data
df1 <- data.frame(icd = c("JAL01", "JAL20", "JAL21", "foo11", "foo22"),
                  x = 1:5)

# get 1st 3 letters
df1$grp <- substr(df1$icd, 1, 3)

# get sum per group
aggregate(x ~ grp, df1, sum)
#   grp x
# 1 foo 9
# 2 JAL 6
```